# How to export large size json feed to MYSQL Table?

Tags: php, mysql, json, scripting, php-7

I am having a PHP script that exports a data from JSON feed to a MYSQL table below is the code I am using.

```
<?php
@ini_set( 'max_execution_time', 0);

require_once 'db_connect.php';

/* DEFINE TABLE NAME AND SOURCE URL HERE */
$str_tbl_name   = 'table_name';
$str_source_url = 'https://www.json-feed.com/example';

/* FETCH DATA FROM RESOURCE LINK */
$str_source_content = file_get_contents($str_source_url);
$arr_data           = json_decode($str_source_content);

$str_date_time  = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$str_start_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($arr_data->meta->start_date));
$str_end_date   = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($arr_data->meta->end_date));
$arr_value_sql  = [];
foreach ($arr_data->data as $data) {
    /* DATA CLEANSING */
    $data->source_subregion        = !empty($data->source_subregion) ? $con_db->real_escape_string($data->source_subregion) : null;
    $data->source_country_code     = !empty($data->source_country_code) ? $con_db->real_escape_string($data->source_country_code) : null;
    $str_input_name                = !empty($data->metadata->search_name) ? $con_db->real_escape_string($data->metadata->search_name) : null;
    $data->document_url            = !empty($data->document_url) ? $con_db->real_escape_string($data->document_url) : null;
    $str_document_tags             = !empty((array) $data->document_tags) ? $con_db->real_escape_string(serialize($data->document_tags)) : null;
    $data->document_sentiment      = !empty($data->document_sentiment) ? $con_db->real_escape_string($data->document_sentiment) : null;
    $data->source_name             = !empty($data->source_name) ? $con_db->real_escape_string($data->source_name) : null;
    $data->document_publish_date   = !empty($data->document_publish_date) ? $con_db->real_escape_string($data->document_publish_date) : null;
    $str_document_matched_keywords = !empty((array) $data->document_matched_keywords) ? $con_db->real_escape_string(implode(',', $data->document_matched_keywords)) : null;
    $data->document_language_code  = !empty($data->document_language_code) ? $con_db->real_escape_string($data->document_language_code) : null;
    $str_document_key_phrases      = !empty((array) $data->document_key_phrases) ? $con_db->real_escape_string(implode(',', $data->document_key_phrases)) : null;
    $data->document_hit_sentence   = !empty($data->document_hit_sentence) ? $con_db->real_escape_string($data->document_hit_sentence) : null;
    $data->document_hidden         = ($data->document_hidden === true) ? 'TRUE' : 'FALSE';
    $str_document_authors          = !empty($data->document_authors[0]->name) ? $con_db->real_escape_string($data->document_authors[0]->name) : null;
    $data->document_city           = !empty($data->document_city) ? $con_db->real_escape_string($data->document_city) : null;

    $str_value_sql = " ("
            . "'{$data->document_publish_date}'"
            . ", '{$data->document_url}'"
            . ", '{$data->source_name}'"
            . ", '{$str_document_authors}'"
            . ", '{$data->source_country_code}'"
            . ", '{$data->source_subregion}'"
            . ", '{$data->document_language_code}'"
            . ", '{$data->source_reach}'"
            . ", '{$data->source_ave}'"
            . ", '{$data->document_sentiment}'"
            . ", '{$str_document_key_phrases}'"
            . ", '{$str_input_name}'"
            . ", '{$str_document_matched_keywords}'"
            . ", '{$data->document_city}'"
            . ")";
    array_push($arr_value_sql, $str_value_sql);
}
```

Now the issue is if the JSON feed is small size data below 100MB all goes well. But one of the JSON feed I have is 1.5GB in size and the PHP runs out of memory even after I allocate 8 GB memory to it.

How do I either get this done in one script run or how to change the script so that it will break up the JSON feed and will export lets says 500 rows at a time to MYSQL table.

Comment: have u tried parsing the file in chunks? like every 1000 rows or so push to the array and insert and then clear the array and do the same for the next 1000?

Comment: Do you have any example to show for this?

Comment: i'll answer in a proper way :) give me a minute please

Answer (score 0):

So regarding what I said in the comment:

Basically when you are building the `str_value_sql` array don't push the entire file to it, do the for loop like

```
for (i=1000; i<number_lines_in_feed; i+=1000) {
  for (j=0; j<i; j++) {
    array_push($arr_value_sql, $str_value_sql);
  }
  run sql query for insert
}
```

mind you that this is just a quick example but the idea here is that you parse the json data object 1000 items at a time and this make the arr_value_sql a lot smaller and would probably make the query memory footprint and such a lot smaller etc... I would suggest trying that ... I hope it fits the structure of your JSON